# Sum larger numbers with decimal points from different files in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sum

Tried using the below command.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {keys[FNR]=$2; cnt=FNR} {x[$2] += $3} END {for(i=1; i<=cnt; ++i) print keys[i],x[keys[i]]}' file1 file2 file3
```

contents in file1

```
"T";  115;"SUM";37;          99215.84
```

contents in file2

```
"T";  115;"SUM";37;          46772.39
```

contents in file3

```
"T";  115;"SUM";37;        1063605.00
```

What I need is the sum of the 2nd and 5th field and to print a line as below;

```
"T";  345;"SUM";37;        1209593.23
```

Comment: @saisureshiva Thanks for the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           FS=OFS=";"
           CONVFMT="%.2f"
     }
     {
          c2+=$2; c5+=$5
     }
     END{ 
          $2=c2; $5=c5; 
          print 
     }' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for that Akshay.